# WCF adding second endpoint using computer name and local domain

Tags: c#, wcf

I'm not very experienced with WCF, as such I'm a little stuck with this one, I allow my WCF service to configure it's own endpoints (my manual attempts have been less than successful). Now this works fine appart from one issue, It adds a second endpoint using the local machine name, and the local windows domain.

My Config file is such:

```xml
  <system.serviceModel>
<behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior>
      <useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
        <defaultPorts>
          <add scheme="https" port="443"/>
        </defaultPorts>
      </useRequestHeadersForMetadataAddress>
      <!-- To avoid disclosing metadata information, set the values below to false before deployment -->
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true"/>
      <!-- To receive exception details in faults for debugging purposes, set the value below to true.  Set to false before deployment to avoid disclosing exception information -->
      <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="true"/>
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<protocolMapping>
    <add binding="basicHttpsBinding" scheme="https" />
</protocolMapping>    
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true" multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" />
```

However when adding this WCF to a WPF application, it generates the following config (Url changed for security)

```xml
<system.serviceModel>
    <bindings>
        <basicHttpBinding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IAdminService">
                <security mode="None">
                    <transport clientCredentialType="None" />
                    <message clientCredentialType="UserName" />
                </security>
            </binding>
            <binding name="BasicHttpsBinding_IAdminService">
                <security mode="Transport" />
            </binding>
        </basicHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
    <client>
        <endpoint address="http://machinename.domain.local/PortalServices/AdminService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IAdminService"
            contract="AdminService.IAdminService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IAdminService" />
        <endpoint address="https://mysite.co.uk/PortalServices/AdminService.svc"
            binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpsBinding_IAdminService"
            contract="AdminService.IAdminService" name="BasicHttpsBinding_IAdminService" />
    </client>
</system.serviceModel>
```

As you can see, it adds a working URL and a local domain URL

```xml
http://machinename.domain.local/PortalServices/AdminService.svc
```

How can i prevent this from being added? as it becomes a bit of a pain having to remember to manually remove it after every deploy/service update.

As Requested, this is one of the Interface classes.

```xml
[ServiceContract]
public interface IAdminService
{
    [OperationContract]
    List<PortalApp> GetApplications();

    [OperationContract]
    int AddApplication(string AppName, string Desc, string version, bool enabled);

    [OperationContract]
    bool EditApplication(int appid, string AppName, string Desc, string version, bool enabled);

    [OperationContract]
    bool AddAppAccess(int appid, Int16 uid);

    [OperationContract]
    bool RemAppAccess(int appid, Int16 uid);

    [OperationContract]
    List<PortalUser> GetUsers();
}
```

Comment: Never seen that behaviour, but then I always do my own configs and usually make self-hosted services. Seems odd it would create two endpoints in the client and also two bindings with different Security Modes, what does the code look like on the service-side?

Comment: The code is pretty standard, I'll post the interface so not to clutter up with actual code (which isn't really relevant anyhow)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, thanks to Jontatas mentioning the fact the endpoints have seperate binding types it got me thinking.

Turns out i had forgotten to remove the http binding from IIS itself (which is not used). Removing that binding from IIS also removed the incorrect binding in the generated config.